# Zorin OS not starting?

Tags: linux, boot, multi-boot, grub, bootloader

I have Zorin OS and Elementary OS installed in the same partition of my computer. I am able to boot Elementary but Zorin OS is not starting. I use grub bootloader.

When I try to start Zorin OS, it always shows splash(Zorin OS startup logo). I installed Zorin OS first and then installed Elementary OS. Please tell me the solution, How can I start Zorin OS?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having the problems you are having because you tried to install both Linux distributions to the same partition. Normally, most people set aside a partition for each Linux or UNIX distribution they are installing to the same hard drive.

I suggest you download the [GParted Live CD](http://gparted.org/livecd.php) and use it to make separate partitions for Zorin OS, and Elementary OS.

For more information on partitioning your hard drive with GParted, look [HERE](http://www.howtoforge.com/partitioning_with_gparted).